# How to return multiple answers in azure qnabot using C#

Tags: c#, azure, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I need a mechanism where I can return more than one answer (most relevant 3 answers according to confidence score) in chatbot using C# .Net core 2.0.

I have a code where I am using BotServices for getting answer to my question.

Have explored on getting multiple answers but only got link to node.js approaches.As one depicted below.

My Code in C#:

```
private readonly BotServices _services;
var response = await 
_services.QnAServices[QnAMakerKey].GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);
```

NodeJS approach on the same:

```
var recognizer = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
knowledgeBaseId: 'set your kbid here',
authKey: 'set your subscription key here',
top: 3});
```

Please guide me through if there is similar approach in C# to get most relevant 3 answers.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is the following. Make a variable to receive all the answers from QnaMaker.

```
var queryResults = await base.GetAnswersAsync(context);
```

QnaMaker will return a answer with the highest score if you don't specify it. To return the first answer:

```
if (queryResults.Length > 0)
{
    var queryResult = queryResults[0].Answer;
}
```

You can make a for-loop through the queryResults and add the answers to an array.

Comment: Not returning results as expected . Have tried this approach before